# Unpack the meaning of this lift function

Tags: scala

I am not sure how the following function works:

```
  def lift[A, B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = _ map f
```

I know it transforms a function which takes a value of type `A` and returns a value of type `B` into a function which takes a value of type `Option[A]` and returns an `Option[B]`. But I am stuck on what the underscore is doing and how the map works. Can someone expand the function definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def lift[A, B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = _ map f
```

it exapnds to

```
def lift[A, B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = x => x map f
```

(this is how underscore works in this context)

The return type is annotated to be `Option[A] => Option[B]`. Thanks to this compiler will know that `x` is of type `Option[A]`. We can say it explicitly, expanding it further

```
def lift[A, B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = (x: Option[A]) => x map f
```

So, the returned function takes an `Option[A]` and maps it using `f`. `Option.map` takes parameter that is a function `A => B` so everything is correct.

Note that since I annotated the type that function takes as a parameter you can now omit the type of lift method like this

```
def lift[A, B](f: A => B) = (x: Option[A]) => x map f
```

All the snippets I wrote in this post are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`_ map f`  in this case returns a function that takes an `Option[A]` and returns an `Option[B]`.

**The `_` in this case is a shortcut to build and return a function** by specifying its argument position.
So here, the position of the `Option[A]` argument.

Whenever this returned function will be further called, it would execute:

`thePassedOptionA map f`

Comment: If I do `lift(math.abs)`, this will returns the following function `Option[Double] => Option[Double]`. I am passing in a function which has the following signature `Double => Double`. How did the underscore convert the first `Double` into an `Option[Double]`?

Comment: It doesn't convert it. They are distinct. You are confused since you may think that the input of the returned type is the same input than the lift's input. _ represents this `Option[Double]` that will be provide by a second call, this time not on the `lift` itself, but on the function returned by lift.

Comment: Take the example of `(_ + _)`.  It returns an `anonymous function` (literal function) that needs two parameters, that will be sum.

Comment: Yes, I understand that example. I just don't get the `_ map f`.

Comment: You understand  `myOptionA.map(f)`, so you may replace `_` by `myOptionA`.  `_` is a placeholder syntax, aiming to build a literal function.  It's like somehow defining:                  `def anonymous(option: Option[A], f: A => B) = option.map(f)`. Note that  `_ map f` is similar to `_.map(f)`